# Does Stackoverflow use Bootstrap?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

As the title goes,

Does Stackoverflow (the website) use any Bootstrap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No*.

[Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) is forced to write every CSS definition manually or he doesn't qualify for his yearly bacon bonus, which would be tragic.

<sub>*Note that Bootstrap didn't exist when the site was first designed, so there's little reason to have worked it in after the fact, among other reasons for not wanting to use it.</sub>

Comment: Haha, cheers for the answer m8.

Comment: Just to confirm the "No". Bacon negotiations are a private matter between Jin and SE management.